# Customized section below quick info section developed in Sitecore 7 behaving differently in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8

I created a custom section named Created/Updated in Sitecore 7 just below the default “Quick info” section as shown below:

[image: Created/updated section in sitcore7]

Recently we migrated our project from Sitecore 7 to Sitecore 8 but “Created/Updated” section developed by us is no more looking like quick info of Sitecore 7. 
The code is similar to Quick info default code used in Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditor namespace in Sitecore.Client.dll

[image: Created/updated section in sitcore8]

As shown above the fields present in “Created/Updated” are not looking like “Quick info” section. Instead, we can see a distinct table and rows for fields and width of these fields is less because of which entire time in Created Time field is not visible at the moment and it is getting cropped. I am not sure how it changed in Sitecore8 and how it can be switched back to the correct view like Quick info of Sitecore 7.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of outputting `<input>` HTML in your second column, just do straight values.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change CSS for your custom component.

First of all, make sure first column has fixed width and second column has `nowrap` style set:

```
td:nth-of-type(1) { width: 110px; }
td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

This will make second column that contains info to occupy whole rest of space after first column.

**Important**: CSS order **does** matter; also you would prefix `td` from example above with selector of your parent container element for your custom panel (not to mess with rest of tables on a page).

Also, you'd probably want to remove borders, to have look and feel like Quick View section has, but from your post it is unclear which element makes borders, likely to be the same TD.

Hope this helps!